# shutil not storing path for random select/copy of files?

Tags: python, shutil

[Edit: see final code below] I'm using the code below to randomly select 5 files from a source directory and then copy them to a new directory. It's giving me an IO error in which it says "No such file or directory 'x' exists" where "x" is the filename without the directory path. Somehow it isn't storing the path in "files." I looked on this forum as well as a shutil tutorial but I can't figure it out. (btw, this is similar to a previous question I asked but the code and error changed. I'll post the final code to that question when I get it working). Thanks in advance!

```
import os
import shutil
import random
import os.path

src_dir = 'C:\\'
target_dir = 'C:\\Test'
src_files = (os.listdir(src_dir))
def valid_path(dir_path, filename):
    full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
    return os.path.isfile(full_path)  
files = [f for f in src_files if valid_path(src_dir, f)]
choices = random.sample(files, 5)
for files in choices:
    shutil.copyfile(files, target_dir)
    print ('Finished!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`shutil.copyfile(files, target_dir)`

to

`shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(src_dir, files), target_dir)`

You're only using the `src_dir` to test whether the full path is valid, then you don't use it again.

**Edit**:  Consider the following

```
src_dir = 'C:\\'
target_dir = 'C:\\Test'
# Create a list of filenames
src_files = (os.listdir(src_dir)) 
# Create a list of full paths (valid)
src_paths = [f for f in [os.path.join(src_dir, f) for f in src_files] if os.path.isfile(f)]
# Do selection
choices = random.sample(src_paths, 5)
for path in choices:
    print path
    shutil.copy(path, target_dir)
    print ('Finished!')
```

Note that I changed `copyfile` to `copy` since you were specifying a destination *directory* and not an destination file.

You could also add a leading `r` before your strings to make them [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html) to avoid having to escape the backslash:

```
dir = 'C:\\Temp\\' # Is the same as
dir = r'C:\Temp\'
```

But the SO syntax highlighter doesn't like it so I took it out

Comment: Nice! This seemed to do the trick. It's now telling me that I don't have permission to write to my destination but it seems to have gotten past the issue of storing paths. Thanks!

Comment: See my edit, I think you need the `copy` function instead of the `copyfile` function.  Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir()` returns filenames only. You will need to use `os.path.join()` to join the path to them.

Answer (score 1):

When you `src_files = os.listdir(src_dir)`, you're getting just a list of filenames.
You then enumerate `[f for f in src_files if valid_path()]`, keeping just a list of filenames.

When you finally `shutil.copyfiles(files, target_dir)`, you're still passing just the list of filenames, not the whole path.

```
files = [os.path.join(src_dir, f) for f in src_files if valid_path(src_dir, f)]
```